# "Dependancy is not satisfiable" in trying to install two drivers for my Epson NX420 printer/scanner

Tags: wireless, drivers, printing, scanner, epson

I am trying to get the wireless scanner part of my Epson NX420 printer working over wifi with my ubuntu 12.10 desktop computer.

I went to the epson website here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule to get the proper drivers.  I downloaded and installed the printer drivers no problem, everything is printing great, but when I downloaded and tried to install the two scanner drivers available on the epson website in the software center I got:

`Dependency is not satisfiable: iscan-data` for iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl3_amd64.deb

and

`Dependancy is not satisfiable: iscan (>=2.21.0)` for iscan-network-nt_1.1.0-2_amd64.deb

How do I satisfy these dependancies?

Also I have been trying to configure the scanner in the simple scan program to no affect, it won't recongnize any scanner.

Thats as far as I got.  Would love some help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two versions of the iscan_2.29 deb-file, one with ltdl3 in the filename and one with ltdl7. For Ubuntu 12.10 you need to download the `iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb` driver. The one you've picked (ltdl3) is for ubuntu 8.04 or earlier as explained in the FAQ at the bottom of the driver page.
Also, `iscan-data_1.22.0-1_all.deb` needs to be installed first.

Comment: Wow.  This community rules.  Thanks a million for your sound advice.  A well earned answer!  Take care I'm going to make some art now!

Comment: Where did you get iscan-data_1.22.0-1_all.deb?

Comment: @zkurtz you get it from the EPSON website http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Answer (score 0):

You try install it whit CUPS, scanning over your browse?

try it if you already no try it

in your browse type it: localhost:631

it will open a interface to you install your print!!!

I holpe help you!!!

Comment: Interesting site I'm not sure what to do on it.  It knew what printer I have and everything.  Pretty cool.  The problem is that I need to figure out how to get the scanner working, printing isn't the problem.  I have (what I hope to be listed above) the proper drivers, but I cant get them to install due to "un-satisfiable dependencies".