# Where is iscan-data_1.22.0-1_all.deb?

Tags: dpkg

I'm trying to set up the scanner driver for my Epson WF-3520 printer.  I started with

```
sudo dpkg -i iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_amd64.deb
```

after downloading that `.deb' file from the [Epson](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/SupportIndex.jsp) website.  Unfortunately, this fails with an error:

```
Unpacking iscan-network-nt (from iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of iscan-network-nt:
 iscan-network-nt depends on iscan (>= 2.29.3); however:
  Package iscan is not installed.

dpkg: error processing iscan-network-nt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 iscan-network-nt
```

Based on previous discussions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267084/dependancy-is-not-satisfiable-in-trying-to-install-two-drivers-for-my-epson-nx) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209795/epson-xp-605-printer-driver-for-ubuntu), I need to start by installing `iscan-data_1.22.0-1_all.deb', but I can't find this.  Does it exist?

**UPDATE:**  Even after finding and installing `iscan-data_1.22.0-1_all.deb`, I get exactly the same error as listed above when I run `sudo dpkg -i iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_amd64.deb`.  This is turning into a different kind of question ... Follow the progress [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393607/printer-scanner-driver-for-epson-workforce-wf-5320)!

Comment: I did find the file in question on GoogleDocs but I'm not sure I would trust the validity of it: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0OFSi_IZfiHallMbFZOMmlVWG8/edit?pli=1

Comment: Interesting, I saw that too and forgot to mention it.  I wonder if I can trust it.

Comment: Short of finding it on the Epson site, it may be the only option.

Comment: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=24992&DSCCHK=6c664adcc21899820883bad3becd133e61e94348 and click on "Accept" shows available Linux driver packages for your printer.

Answer (score 2):

old link to Epson page no more exists
new link here: http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.html

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded iscan-data from 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0OFSi_IZfiHallMbFZOMmlVWG8/edit?pli=1 and installed it through Ubuntu Software Center. Installed both `iscan_2.29.3-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb` and `iscan-plugin-cx4400_2.1.3-1_amd64.deb` downloaded from http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX.  Give printer no, say, CX5500 and Choose 'Linux' in the OS > click on the magnifying glass (search), Click on 'Download' > Accept and download.

The Printer driver pips-common-3.0 is still giving trouble due to dependencies' issue. Could overcome `./configure` step, but stuck in '`make`' due to some header file error. Worked around by natively choosing System Settings > Printers > Add etc. Keep the printer connected and switched on.

This is reinstallation and earlier also by similar workaround, my EPSON CX5500 AIO Scanner, printer and Copier was working (better than Windows 7).

Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

For all Linux drivers for Epson go here:

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Enter the name of your printer ...

Some drivers have to be installed in the right order, iscan-network was giving an error until I first installed the other drivers first.

Comment: He's clearly tried this.

Answer (score -2):

According to the [Epson FAQ](http://download.ebz.epson.net/faq/linux/faq_ls_00002.html) you need to install the `iscan` and `iscan_data` packages from [this Epson web page](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=DE&CN2=&DSCMI=24992&DSCCHK=162ea935c9934ad018fbfcd10deec7b623725f72)

Comment: seems like the right idea, but the [second] link provided seems to be in some other language.  @douggro in the comments above seems to have the right link.

Comment: second link is down ATM